# Confused on writing react-router code

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the difference in writing react-router in following different ways?

1.) As seen in react-router [github](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) page

```
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="users" component={Users}>
        <Route path="/user/:userId" component={User}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

2.) [webpack code for hugeapp](https://github.com/thereactivestack/kickstart-hugeapp/blob/master/modules/TodoApp/client/routes.jsx)

```
import TodoApp from './TodoApp';
import TodoMain from './TodoMain';

export default {
  path: '/',
  component: TodoApp,
  indexRoute: { component: TodoMain },
  childRoutes: []
};
```

3.) [webpack for simple app](https://github.com/thereactivestack/kickstart-simple/blob/master/modules/TodoApp/client/routes.jsx)

```
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import TodoApp from './TodoApp';
import TodoMain from './TodoMain';

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={TodoApp}>
    <IndexRoute component={TodoMain} />
  </Route>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at the [Alternate Configuration](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/basics/RouteConfiguration.md#alternate-configuration) section on official docs. It explains that react-router can either accept JSX or a plain-object, each having two mandatory properties: `path` and `component`. The `indexRoute` property of that plain-object is "replaced" (in fact, it's not) by `<IndexRoute />` component; and `childRoutes` is the same as `children` prop of a component which is filled by whatever is encapsulated into the component.

So, the

```
export default {
  path: '/',
  component: TodoApp,
  indexRoute: { component: TodoMain },
  childRoutes: []
};
```

configuration can be written in JSX way:

```
export default (
  <Route path="/" component={TodoApp}>
    <IndexRoute component={TodoMain} />
  </Route>
);
```

Comment: Where does  ``export default  {``  come from?

Comment: It's ES6 module export syntax, see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export). The `default` keyword means that when you import from that source, whatever variable you assign the import to, will contain the default export. Non-default exports will be composed into an object, each property's key is the name of the export. You can have many `export` statements and only one `export default`.